# GROUP BY date range

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, group-by

```
CREATE TABLE `connectionLog` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `serverTimeConnected` datetime NOT NULL,
  `serverTimeDisconnected` datetime  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

with this query i get all IDs where serverTimeConnected is in one hour.

```
SELECT  HOUR( `serverTimeConnected`) as STUNDE, 
    count(`ID`) as HITS 
FROM    `connectionLog` 
GROUP BY HOUR( `serverTimeConnected`)
```

but i need all IDs between serverTimeConnected and serverTimeDisconnected.

```
ID  serverTimeConnected serverTimeDisconnected
1   10:00:00            10:10:00    
2   10:00:00            11:10:00    
3   10:00:00            12:10:00
```

I need a result - like

```
STUNDE  HITS
10,     3
11,     2
12,     1
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I've found this solution

```
 SELECT Stunden.ID, COUNT(Stunden.ID) as HITS FROM Stunden
INNER JOIN connectionLog cl 
  ON (
    (ADDTIME(DATE_FORMAT(cl.serverTimeConnected,'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'),CONCAT(Stunden.ID,":00:00")) 
      BETWEEN cl.serverTimeConnected AND cl.serverTimeDisconnected)
    OR
      (ADDTIME(DATE_FORMAT(cl.serverTimedisConnected,'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'),CONCAT(Stunden.ID,":00:00")) 
      BETWEEN cl.serverTimeConnected AND cl.serverTimeDisconnected)
     )

GROUP BY Stunden.ID
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f3b0/11 (updated)

The table `Stunden` is a list of all distinct hours available.
A simple `INNER JOIN` when the hour is between connection and disconnection (with a look at the day) get us the number of match that we searching.
Then `Group by` hours and we match the right `HITS`.

Comment: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a1ab/1/0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a1ab/1/0) works. But i have an other problem: serverTimeConnected = "2013-08-20 23:00:00" and serverTimeDisconnected = "2013-08-21 01:10:00"

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please note that's a simple query. Maybe is more clean to use a store procedure or a function and avoid the table Stunden.

Answer (score 0):

How about `group_concat`

```
SELECT  HOUR( `serverTimeConnected`) as STUNDE, 
        count(`ID`) as HITS,
        group_concat(id) as IDs
FROM    `connectionLog` 
GROUP BY HOUR( `serverTimeConnected`)
```

Comment: just a note. `The result [of group_concat] is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024`

Comment: I think that this isn't the answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

You may take a look to  TIMEDIFF

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Comment: While pointing the OP to a possible solution may be helpful, relevant code or samples are preferred.

Comment: Good argument. But it's a usefull hint anyways!